# What is the problem with the display : inline-block in my code

Tags: html, css, display

I try to create a simple layout using display:inline-block

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 390px;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px;
}

.box1 {
  background: turquoise;
}

.box2 {
  background: #f5c402;
}

.box3 {
  background: lightsalmon;
}

.box4 {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1 box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis illum sapiente, autem numquam modi dolorem perferendis iure quaerat corrupti nobis!
</div>
<div class="box2 box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias incidunt tempore minima ut asperiores eveniet error eligendi fuga deserunt numquam, voluptas impedit qui repellendus quam architecto, blanditiis unde explicabo quasi.
</div>
<div class="box3 box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque dolorum nobis hic? Illum omnis sequi molestiae dignissimos voluptates voluptatibus dolores quaerat non aliquam quis natus maiores quod aut aperiam labore doloremque deserunt laboriosam cupiditate
  possimus quidem consectetur, laborum quos sed?
</div>
<div class="box4 box">
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque dolorum nobis hic? Illum omnis sequi molestiae dignissimos voluptates voluptatibus dolores quaerat non aliquam quis natus maiores quod aut aperiam labore doloremque deserunt laboriosam cupiditate
  possimus quidem consectetur, laborum quos sed?
</div>
```

But it gives unexpected results have a look at the Screenshot. Please guide me on why is that. Is there something wrong with my code or am I missing some hidden concept behind display:inline-block?
[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Please use good language to post your question. please try to be nice.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add `vertical-align: top;` on your `.box` element.

Here's the example, with the code you had provided:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 390px;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px;
  vertical-align: top; // here's the magic
}

.box1 {
  background: turquoise;
}

.box2 {
  background: #f5c402;
}

.box3 {
  background: lightsalmon;
}

.box4 {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
  <div class="box1 box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis illum sapiente, autem numquam modi dolorem perferendis iure quaerat corrupti nobis!
  </div>
  <div class="box2 box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias incidunt tempore minima ut asperiores eveniet error eligendi fuga deserunt numquam, voluptas impedit qui repellendus quam architecto, blanditiis unde explicabo quasi.
  </div>
  <div class="box3 box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque dolorum nobis hic? Illum omnis sequi molestiae dignissimos voluptates voluptatibus dolores quaerat non aliquam quis natus maiores quod aut aperiam labore doloremque deserunt laboriosam cupiditate
    possimus quidem consectetur, laborum quos sed?
  </div>
  <div class="box4 box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque dolorum nobis hic? Illum omnis sequi molestiae dignissimos voluptates voluptatibus dolores quaerat non aliquam quis natus maiores quod aut aperiam labore doloremque deserunt laboriosam cupiditate
    possimus quidem consectetur, laborum quos sed?
  </div>
```

For a better approach, I suggest you to wrap all the `.box` elements on a parent element `.boxes-container` and use `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` on this new parent element.

Here's the solution for the second case:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.boxes_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 390px;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px;
}

.box1 {
  background: turquoise;
}

.box2 {
  background: #f5c402;
}

.box3 {
  background: lightsalmon;
}

.box4 {
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes_container">
  <div class="box1 box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis illum sapiente, autem numquam modi dolorem perferendis iure quaerat corrupti nobis!
  </div>
  <div class="box2 box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias incidunt tempore minima ut asperiores eveniet error eligendi fuga deserunt numquam, voluptas impedit qui repellendus quam architecto, blanditiis unde explicabo quasi.
  </div>
  <div class="box3 box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque dolorum nobis hic? Illum omnis sequi molestiae dignissimos voluptates voluptatibus dolores quaerat non aliquam quis natus maiores quod aut aperiam labore doloremque deserunt laboriosam cupiditate
    possimus quidem consectetur, laborum quos sed?
  </div>
  <div class="box4 box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque dolorum nobis hic? Illum omnis sequi molestiae dignissimos voluptates voluptatibus dolores quaerat non aliquam quis natus maiores quod aut aperiam labore doloremque deserunt laboriosam cupiditate
    possimus quidem consectetur, laborum quos sed?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use inline-flex instead of inline-block. It works.

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 390px;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px;
}

.box1 {
  background: turquoise;
}

.box2 {
  background: #f5c402;
}

.box3 {
  background: lightsalmon;
}

.box4 {
  background: teal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with `display:inline-block` you may like to use `vertical-align` property. In your case:

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `float:left;` to `.box`

Comment: This is not a good approach, because it requires to user a `clear: both` on the next element on the DOM tree. Is better to use `display: flex` on a parent element.